# Update nested object in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, redux

I'm using a Redux (ReKotlin) implementation to my Android Kotlin project but I have an issue updating nested objects in array.

In Swift I can change a value of a nested object like bellow:

```
state.list = state.list.map { listItem in
        if listItem.id == action.payload.id {
            var listItem = listItem
            listItem.title = action.payload.newTitle
            return listItem
          } else {
            return listItem
          }
        }
```

I have tried with map() and filter() but no luck.

//Object

```
class ListItem (
   var title: String
)
```

// state.list

```
list = ArrayList<ListItem>
```

Comment: If you want to mutate objects instead of creating new ones, use `forEach` instead of `map`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Could you post an example with the above info? I tried with forEach but didn't work

Comment: I'm not familiar with Swift. Does the line `listItem.title = action.payload.newTitle` mutate the existing object, or create a new one? In Java/Kotlin/C# syntax, that would mutate the object, but then I don't understand why you would have to create the shadowing `listItem` variable.

Answer (score 0):

To mutate existing objects:

```
state.list.forEach { listItem ->
    if (listItem.id == action.payload.id) {
        listItem.title = action.payload.newTitle
    }
}
```

`forEach` simply performs an action on each item, so there's nothing to return from the lambda.

To create a new list of objects, presumably immutable data class objects:

```
state.list = state.list.map { listItem ->
    if (listItem.id == action.payload.id) {
        listItem.copy(title = action.payload.newTitle)
    } else {
        listItem
    }
}
```

`map`'s lambda must return an object that will replace the original object in the new list that's generated. Lambdas implicitly return the result of their last expression, so you don't need the `return` keyword.

Comment: I tried with the forEach but I get this error ->  kotlin.Unit cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Comment: Maybe you can add your code to your question and show some context about what types the variables/properties are.

Comment: ArrayList is a specific type of MutableList, but the `map` function returns a read-only List, so you have a type mismatch. Generally, you should avoid combining a `var` read-write property with a MutableList because then it is mutable in two different ways, which can lead to easily creating bugs. I recommend changing the variable type to a read-only List, so when you declare it, you should just put an empty list as the beginning value. `var list = emptyList<ListItem>()`.